# Could we show if someone is typing on chat?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, chat

When @ at someone, it would be good to know when he/she types an answer. Just like in popular IMs like Facebook, Gmail etc.

Comment: What would this be good for?

Comment: Recently asked on [metase] [Typing indicator in chat](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/124166)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I disagree, basically because we aren't an IM client - we're a chat room. I think all that would do is just add more data for the servers to transmit, and doesn't really benefit us as a whole in the end.

Also it's slightly creepy I find.. Much easier to just wait for that sound you hear when someone @'s you back.

It's also a bit ineffective when you have 20+ people in the room.

Comment: **Dat suspense** when you see: "Clippy is typing..."

Answer (score 11):

It doesn't work reliably anyway.

[image]
<sub>(source: [thedoghousediaries.com](http://thedoghousediaries.com/comics/uncategorized/2011-12-26-59358b5.png))</sub>

Comment: ahahahhahaa. perfect.

Comment: @slhck So I would wait days for reply?

Comment: I agree with Simon Sheehan but this example may just be due to a bad algorithm for detecting whether someone is writing.

Comment: @N.N. Either that, or people are really stopping to type frequently. Which, frankly, happens to me way too often. It really makes me nervous.