# Why we can't we show that chatting user is typing?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, chat

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Could we show if someone is typing on chat?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/4604/could-we-show-if-someone-is-typing-on-chat)

Consider this scenario

A and B were chatting for an specific answer and why can't we show the specific user is typing when he types the post on a chat?

Comment: -1 I hope not. Typing indicators are only annoying, e.g. when you need to do something else for a few minutes in between and return only to find "Hey send that message already", "What are you typing" and similar responses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the person isn't online the avatar will be faded out/not be visible in the list of users.

[image]

I don't see why we need another specific check for that.

Comment: i agree with you and why can't i accept the answer now if i try to accept answer it says you can accept it after 3 mins,now i reedited the question pls review it

Comment: @vikki you need to wait for a little while before accepting an answer.  This is in place to prevent gaming of the system.  Be patient and you'll be able to accept in a few minutes.

Comment: It's faded if they haven't been active for a while though, not when they're not online. I've seen my avatar faded a lot of times.